# angularjs will not bind data to $scope after $http call and promise return

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, angular-formly

Having an issue with binding data to a var named `$scope`things. I call mysql database and it sends data over through express.

```
app.get('/options', function(req, res)
{
var arr = [];
var query = "SELECT * FROM memberships";
con.query(query, function(err, result)
{
    if (err)
    {
        console.log("error retriving memberships from the db " + err);
        throw err;
    }
    res.send(result);
}); 


 /* server side of things  */
```

now to go to the angular side.

```
    app.controller('MainController', ['$http', '$scope', '$log', 
    'getmemOptions', function($http, $log, $scope, getmemOptions)

    {
    var gymmem = this;
    gymmem.onSubmit = onSubmit;

    gymmem.options;
    $scope.things;
    var promise = $http.get('/options');

    promise.then(function(payload)
    {
     $scope.things = angular.copy(payload.data);
     alert(JSON.stringify($scope.things)); // 1st call view $scope.things
});

    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.things)); // 2nd call view $scope.things
```

In my first call to `JSON.stringify($scope.things)` I can see that it pull the correct information from the database; however the second call yields undefined. I am aware of the asynchronous nature of javascript of how the `$http` call will return a promise. I believe I am handling the promise right, but if I am not please let me know how I can change things up. Thank you in advance!!

**EDIT**

Here is angular-formly template.

```
     gymmem.model = 
    {
        first_n: '',
        last_n: '',
        email: '',
        age: '',
        memberships: '',
    };

    gymmem.fields = [
        {
            key: 'first_n',
            type: 'input',
            model: gymmem.model.f_name,
            templateOptions: 
            {
                type: 'text',
                label: 'First Name',
                placeholder: 'Enter your first name',
                required: true
            }
        },

       {
            key: 'last_n',
            type: 'input',
           // model: gymmem.model.l_name,
            templateOptions: 
            {
                type: 'text',
                label: 'Last Name',
                placeholder: 'Enter your last name',
                required: true
            }
        },

        {
            key: 'email',
            type: 'input',
            //model: gymmem.model.email,
            templateOptions: 
            {
                type: 'text',
                label: 'Email Address',
                placeholder: 'Enter your email address',
                required: true
            },
            hideExpression: '!model.first_n || !model.last_n' 
        }, 

         {
            key: 'age',
            type: 'input',
            //model: gymmem.model.age,
            templateOptions: 
            {
                type: 'number',
                label: 'Age (must be 16+)',
                placeholder: 'Enter your age',
                required: true
            },
            //check if customer is 16+
            validators:
            {
                    ofAge: function($viewValue, $modelValue, scope)
                    {
                        var age = $viewValue || $modelValue;
                        if (age >= 16)
                            return true;
                        return false;
                    }
            }
        },

         {
            key: 'memberships',
            type: 'select',
            model: gymmem.model.membership,
            templateOptions: 
            {
                label: 'Membership Types',
                required: true,
                placeholder: "Select Membership",
                options: $scope.things//[{"name":"Martial Arts Membership","value":45},{"name":"Regular Gym Membership","value":30},{"name":"Cardio Classes Membership","value":35}]


            }
        },

    ]; 

    function onSubmit()
    {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(gymmem.model), null, 2);
            $http.post('/', gymmem.model).success(function(req)
            {
                gymmem.model = {};
                console.log("Front end data " +req);
            }).error(function(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };


   }

]);
```

Here just in case is the html.

```
<body ng-app="GymApp" ng-controller="MainController as gymmem">

<div class="container col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <form ng-submit="gymmem.onSubmit()" novalidate>
        <h1> Buy Gym Membership(s) </h1>
        <formly-form model="gymmem.model" fields="gymmem.fields">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button">Submit</button>
        </formly-form>
    </form>
</div>  
</body>
```

[{"name":"Martial Arts Membership","value":45},{"name":"Regular Gym Membership","value":30},{"name":"Cardio Classes Membership","value":35}] is the data I want $scope.things to have. The data here is being processed through the $http.get() call.

Sorry for formatting issues. New to stackoverflow posting and somewhat in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you're handling the `$http` call just fine if you're getting the results in your first `alert()`.

The issue here seems to be within your controller declaration:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$http', '$scope', '$log', 
'getmemOptions', function($http, $log, $scope, getmemOptions)
```

You have mismatching dependency injections. Notice how `$scope` is your 2nd injection, but in your controller function you're referring to it as `$log`. So you're not actually binding anything to `$scope` here. You're really trying to bind it to `$log`.

Change the order of your dependencies in your controller declaration to this:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$http', '$scope', '$log', 
'getmemOptions', function($http, $scope, $log, getmemOptions)
```

Comment: I changed the order of dependencies; however that wasn't the issue. Before I had it bound to variable called "var options" but I added in $scope to see if that could change anything. I am new to angularjs so if there is anything simple, please let me know. Also, why the downvote?

Comment: @SimronPatel, Binding to a variable called options will only work if you're using the ControllerAs syntax which it seems you're trying to do with `gymmem`. If you're getting the data, then you're not properly binding it to the template. Could you also provide your template code? The downvote wasn't me. I'll bump you back up, this is definitely a valid question.

Comment: Sure, give me a moment. Thanks for the bump.